# How can I set file upload field in custom product edit tab in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, admin

Here is my file path

> /Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Custom.php

In that I already added text field like

```
/**
 * Example text field config
 *
 * @param $sortOrder
 * @return array
 */
protected function getVideoUrl($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Video Url'),
                    'formElement' => Field::NAME,
                    'componentType' => Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_VIDEO_URL,
                    'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Now I need to add file upload field in that
How can I set file upload filed in that

[image]

Comment: try this link https://dolphinwebsolution.com/how-to-add-a-custom-field-at-product-form-page-magento-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add This and First Click on Add New Product Form. After Save Your Image Data Modify modifyData() function for set image Array.

```
public function getFileUploaderField()
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Upload Image'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'previewTmpl' => 'Magento_Catalog/image-preview',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/uploader/uploader',
                    'formElement' => "fileUploader",
                    'dataScope' => "image_upload",
                    'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => 10,
                    'visible' => 1,
                    'uploaderConfig' => ['url' => 'your_router/contoller/upload"'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```